# How to create a function that takes generic parameters with TypScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I need to create a function that takes an array as a parameter and returns a sum from a specific value.

My interface:

```
export interface IStatistic {
  allStudyTime: number;
}
```

And object which contains array of objects. Like so: `statistics: IStatistic[]`

```
 const { statistics } = useAppSelector(state => state.statistic);
```

And reduce calculation which i need to convert into generic function as util.

```
  const sumStudyTime = statistics.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
    return previousValue + currentValue.allStudyTime;
  }, 0);
```

This should look something like this but i don't know how to manage it with typescript:

```
export const calculateSum = (array: <T[]>) => {
 return array.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
    return previousValue + currentValue.numberOfStudies;
}
```

Comment: Do you actually want anything generic? Given that you access `numberOfStudies`, that would have to be `array: IStatistic[]`. Also note your function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Yes, i would to make it generic. I have just added some corrections into code.

Comment: But you access a _specific property_, what are you expecting to be generic? How would you _use_ this if you had it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe you are right. I didn't think about it like this. I'm using reduce function in many places but i'm using always the same array of object, so i wanted create one fucntion to get rid of code repetition

Answer (score 0):

You sound to implement an equivalent of [Lodash `sumBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sumBy) (and many other utils libraries):

> `iteratee` [...] is invoked for each element in array to generate the value to be summed

Example:

```
var objects = [{ 'n': 4 }, { 'n': 2 }, { 'n': 8 }, { 'n': 6 }];
 
_.sumBy(objects, function(o) { return o.n; });
// => 20
```

If you *really* want to re-implement it yourself, you could do something like:

```
function sumBy<T>(list: T[], iteratee: (item: T) => number) {
  return list
    .map(iteratee)
    .reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0);
}
```

And if the lists you manage always have the same property name to be summed:

```
function sumByNbOfStudies<T extends { numberOfStudies: number; }>(list: T[]) {
  return sumBy(list, (item) => item.numberOfStudies);
}
```